# R: remove columns and rows

Tags: r, matrix

I've got the following matrix:

```
mat <- matrix(c(1,2,0,9,8,0,0,0,0),ncol = 3)
```

Now I want to remove all the rows and columns that have a rowsum equal to 0 AND a columnsum equal to 0. So here I would like to return:

```
1 2
9 8
```

I've tried to use `rowSums(mat)==0  && colSums(mat)==0`, but I wan't find it.

Comment: why are you using `adj` instead of `mat`? Also you should use `&` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove all rows that sum to 0 and all columns that sum to 0,

```
 mat[!!rowSums(mat), !!colSums(mat)]
 #     [,1] [,2]
 #[1,]    1    9
 #[2,]    2    8
```

But, if you want to remove where both conditions satisfy, i.e.

```
  mat1 <- matrix(c(1,2,0,0,9,8,0,0, 0,0,0,0, 4,6,0,0), ncol=4)
  indx <- !(!rowSums(mat1) & !colSums(mat1))
  mat1[indx,indx]
  #     [,1] [,2] [,3]
  #[1,]    1    9    4
  #[2,]    2    8    6
  #[3,]    0    0    0
```

However, this works only for square matrix, For example:

```
  mat2 <- matrix(c(1,2,0,0,9,8,0,0, 0,0,0,0), ncol=3)
  rowSums(mat2)==0 & colSums(mat2)==0
  # [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
  #Warning message:
  #In rowSums(mat1) == 0 & colSums(mat1) == 0 :
  #longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```